# Post route is not returning any response

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I have an express API and there is a post route to create categories and products. But the post route is not functioning correctly. When I send a request to post route it's not reaching the route. However, when I send to get: /admin route it's reaching the route.

```
const express = require('express');
const { Category } = require('../models/categories');
const { Product } = require('../models/products');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync')
const adminRouter = express.Router();

//Reaching this route
adminRouter.get('/', catchAsync(async(req, res)=>{
    res.send({msg: 'HELLO'})
}))

//Not reaching at all
adminRouter.post('/category/create',  catchAsync(async (req, res)=>{
        const categoryData = req.body 
        console.log(req.body);
        const category = await Category.create(categoryData);
        res.status(201).json(category)
    }))


adminRouter.post('/product/create', catchAsync(async(req, res)=>{
    const productData = req.body
    const product = await Product.create(productData);
    res.status(201).json(product);
}))

module.exports = {adminRouter}
```

And this is my `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { adminRouter } = require('./routes/admin');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}))
app.use(cors())
app.use('/admin', adminRouter)
module.exports = {app}
```

This is what I get when I send request from Postman

[image]

As you can see no status code and no response body. However when I send request to get route it's returning correct response.

Comment: what do you get in `console.log(req.body);`? Does it even log? Check `catchAsync` as well. May be you are catching an exception there and that is blocking your response

Comment: If you are not getting a response to only some of your requests this can mean two things. The first is that you are not using async code properly and are never returning a request. The second is that your datastore is really really slow.  Its likely that you have some improper async code. You should put debug statements in your code to figure out where it fails to continue the flow properly. Better yet write a unit test.

Comment: @ShivamSood Not getting anything in console.log also I tried deleting catchAsync. The same result, no luck

Comment: Is your other post route working? `/product/create`

Comment: It's not working